# how to configure tab as delimited in using CSVFormat?

Tags: java, csv

I am using org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat to output a csv file. My configuration is as below:

```
String[]   HEADERS     = {"sku", "question", "annotation", "answer", "url", "answerType"};
CSVFormat  csvInFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(HEADERS);
CSVPrinter printer     = new CSVPrinter(bw, csvInFormat);
```

This would print the csv with comma delimited. How to output the content with tab as the delimiter?

Comment: You also can make this one change to an existing Format `CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter('\t')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use tab as delimeter, use `CSVFormat.TDF`:

```
CSVFormat  csvInFormat = CSVFormat.TDF.withHeader(HEADERS);
```

Read more about this [CSVFormat.TDF config here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#TDF)